# How to improve on this connection pool design?

Tags: java, database, queue, connection-pooling, producer-consumer

First off, I am developing my own implementation of DBCP (database connection pooling), as such,

**I won't accept any suggestions to use 3rd party DBCP like c3p0.**

I'm using the producer-consumer design model as the main design template for my DBCP.

```
             PRODUCER | CONSUMER
Pn, ... P3, P2, P1 >>   << C1, C2, C3, ... Cn
```

For both producer and consumer, I use LinkedList queue.

#### PRODUCER Queue

It would be populated by a maximum number of SQLConnectionWrapper instances. I have taken steps to ensure the connections are unique in the queue. Upon .close(),  the connection would,

- first, remove the first element in the C-queue, if any,
- else, queue into the P-Queue.

I employ a house-keeper thread to remove stale/expired connections in the queue, and to spawn new connections to keep the minimum number of connections as configured.

#### CONSUMER Queue

It would be populated by FutureTask instances. Apps using my DBCP would call

```
Connection conn = dbcp.getConnection(long timeout);
```

which would,

- first create a Consumer FutureTask,
- remove the first element in the P-queue, if any,
- else, queue into the C-queue,
- blocking on .get(timeout) until it is 'fed' by a Producer or time-out, which ever comes first.

#### My Question

Can this design can be further improved? Any notable weaknesses?

My priority is stability in a concurrent usage environment. I've learned from my current testing that it needs synchronization on both sides since 2 queues are involved.

Right now, I am exploring ideas like :

- reduce the 2 queues into 1 deque (though I have trouble thinking on how to get the P-side to annihilate the C-side)
- create a synchronized annihilator thread, removing the need for PRODUCER and CONSUMER to check each other.

Comment: any reason you're using linkedlist as a queue rather than one of the many queue impl's in j.u.c?

Comment: Project is 1 week old. I use LinkedList because project is in Proof-Of-Concept stage. Besides, synchronization problems detected by testing were external in nature. The change to j.u.c. will come later.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have said you will not accept any third party pool suggestions. I guess u mean any third party connection pool.

What you can look is something like [apache commons connection pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/guide/index.html), that provides pooling facilities for any object. So while i mean no offense and dont want to discourage you, i think you are trying to re-invent the wheel.

Having said that, the link above gives a very high level design of the generic pool. Check how to use the pool and you will get a fair idea as to what is going on and will help you with your design too.

Comment: None taken. This design idea is original to me and started last week. Previously, I have reviewed and tested a DBCP implementation in Openfire open-source code. IMO, I found its design did not fairly allocate connections to waiting consumer threads. Hence, I'm using queue so both Producer and Consumer can be managed in a fair 'first-come-first-serve' basis.

Comment: I wish to update that the annihilator thread is working and keeping the synchronization between P-C intact. Overall, project is complete and I have to focus on other projects. I still welcome any suggestions to the question. If there are no updates for the coming 2 weeks, I'll consider closing this question as unanswered.